# Is it possible to automatically invoke a problemMatcher from extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making an extension, where I'd like to invoke a problemMatcher peridically (or bound to event, whatever is possible). Is it possible without the user having to create a new tasks.json everytime on any new project? I'd like it to be able to function on any randomly opened file, not just a solution.

Would it be possible from a VSCode extension?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the diagnostics API? It allows you to create errors / warnings for the problems view programatically, but without problem matchers.

Comment: @Gama11 Sounds promising, never heard of that API